# H2 compact failed on big db

Tags: java, database, h2

I have an application using an h2 db.
Actually images are stored in CLOB field in base64. But I want to migrate it to Blob and decod base64 value.
The migration work fine on small db like 300mo and the size is really reduced. but I've a 800mo db, and after the migration 2400mo ... When I leave the aplication the db is not compact (I set  -Dh2.maxCompactTime=120000).

I don't know why, maybe I've forget something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to fully compact a database is to run the statement [`SHUTDOWN COMPACT`](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#shutdown).

If the database is not fully compacted yet, it shrinks some more if you open and then close it again (but only if you close all connections).

To fully compress the database, even better is to create a SQL script (for example using `SCRIPT TO`) and re-create the database (for example using `RUNSCRIPT`).

Comment: Thanks, finnaly I script and re-construct my database, it's work fine. cause SHUTDOW COMPACT do nothing